# How to parse data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column name called Username in my table in SQL Server 2008.
Username has following data

```
Username
corp\abc
corp\petern
corp\timw
```

and so on

I need my Username to be

```
Username
abc
petern
timw
```

how do I parse the data in Username to skip corp\ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**PARSENAME**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) to split the data but the function uses dot (`.`) as the delimiter. So, you have to first replace the backward slashes (`\`) with period or dot (`.`).

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9afd/11)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( 
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES
     ('corp\abc'),
     ('corp\corporate\'),
     ('corp\yescorp'),
     ('corp\def'),
     ('\corpabc\'),
     ('corpabc\');

SELECT  username
    ,   PARSENAME(REPLACE(username, '\', '.'), 1) AS usernameonly
FROM    users;
```

*Output*:

```
USERNAME            USERNAMEONLY
-----------------   ------------
corp\abc            abc
corp\corporate\ 
corp\yescorp        yescorp
corp\def            def
\corpabc\   
corpabc\
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use following expression to extract username:

```
select substring (username, charindex ('\', username, 1) + 1, len(username))
```

If there is no backslash in username function will return entire username - practical if you mix sql server and Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update dbo.Users
Set    Username = replace(Username, 'corp\\', '');
```

Please check the quoting beforehand, by first checking whether the results of select seem ok (in general it's a good practice with data updating statements):

```
select replace(Username, 'corp\\', '') from dbo.Users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the username like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('corp\username',LEN('corp\username')-PATINDEX('%\%','corp\username'))
```

=>

```
SELECT RIGHT(username,LEN(username)-PATINDEX('%\%',username))
```

This work on text, nvarchar(n - max)